# UIPickerView doesn't play well with @IBDesignable

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, uipickerview, ibdesignable

I'm creating a custom `@IBDesignable` component that embeds a `UIPickerView` on white background. Everything looks great at runtime. In the Interface Builder however, my picker view looks like this:

[image: UIPickerView & @IBDesignable]

Any ideas how to get rid of the dark overlay?